# How can I run main function of Cplex from c#?

Tags: c#, cplex

I can run a simple Cplex model from C#. There is no problem about it. But I have a big project that has lots of .mod and .dat files. In these .mod files there are main functions. Can I run these functions? In C#, program solves only model and gives result(objective function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class OplModel in C# you may call the function main that will call the main in OPL.

In CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\dotnet\x64_windows_vs2017\CSharp\OplRunSample

see OplRunsample.cs where you may read

```
if (opl.ModelDefinition.hasMain())
            {
                status = opl.Main();
```